# ios : delete Event from server when deleted from iphone calendar app

Tags: ios

I managed to add the event and delete it from iPhone calendar programatically. But How do i know that user has deleted the event (created by my app) from calendar so that i can delete it from web server ??

Comment: you can set a flag value when user created event ,and change your flag value when user deleted his event , like that you can manage your event.

Comment: but how will i know that user has deleted his events ?

Comment: when you are trying to create event that time you just set value in your server side,now user want to delete event that time you have to set value and pass to your server side and and check event if event present than update it